# Execute function after multiple elements were loaded

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, extjs4

I can't find how to bind event to several elements in ext.js, or any specific event fired after initialization of all the elements on the page, so I want to ask how to bind event to several elements on the page or fire it after all the components on the page will be initialized.

Answer (score 0):

in the load event of the body just attach the event what ever it is to what ever elements

Example 
Java Script

```
window.onload = function()
{
var Elements = document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');
for(var i =0;i<Elements.length;i++)
{
Elements[i].onclick = function(e)
{
//do what you want to do here to be handled on the onclick event
}
}
}
```

Regards 
i am here for any comments

Comment: Please, read the question first. I talk about EXT.JS 4 and it's event system.